# Is it safe to browse the web with Firefox during Ubuntu install?

Tags: installation, networking, firefox, language-support, locale

As asked in the title. I clicked on one of the links in the Quantal installer (set up via UNetbootin) and it launched Firefox.

Will using it for a longer time during install cause conflict with language packs that I'm installing (example: Polish)?

Comment: If the installer installs something crucial to Firefox, you'll get a notification to the effect of "Firefox needs to be restarted."

Comment: @Piskvor Why is that? Isn't the live firefox running from liveCD/usb? So installing the real firefox shouldn't affect this one.

Answer (score 7):

Should be fine.  Might cause the install to take a little longer, but probably nothing serious, especially if it's just random browsing and not, for example, playing big heavy Flash games at a site like Kongregate (assuming you even have Flash available in the installer environment, which I don't know the answer to off the top of my head).

Comment: Practically anything (including Flash) can be installed in the live environment, just like you would on a normal desktop... But it won't persist to your new installation.